# Problems with sending text messages to specific channels using discord.py modals

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

With the addition of Interaction, the code got a little complicated, but I don't know what to do.
I would like to send the input value to a specific channel using Modal.

```py
import discord
from discord import app_commands,Interaction,ui,ButtonStyle,SelectOption

GUILD_ID=1219579422353391666

class MyClient(discord.Client):
  async def on_ready(self):
    global channel
    channel = client.get_channel(1219730624206868664)
    await self.wait_until_ready()
    await tree.sync(guild= discord.Object(id=GUILD_ID))
    print(f"{self.user} 에 로그인하였습니다!")
intents= discord.Intents.all()
client = MyClient(intents=intents)
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

@tree.command(guild= discord.Object(id=GUILD_ID),name="ping", description="pong")
async def pingpong(interaction:Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message("pong")
    
@tree.command(guild= discord.Object(id=GUILD_ID),name="testmodal", description="1123")
async def mkmodal(interaction:Interaction):
  class ModalExample(ui.Modal,title="modal"):
    answer = ui.TextInput(
      label="modal1",
      style=discord.TextStyle.short, # long
      placeholder="des",
      default="hello"
    )
    async def on_submit(self, interaction: Interaction):
      await interaction.response.send_message(channel.answer)
  await interaction.response.send_modal(ModalExample())
```

I've tried a lot of different ways, but they're not working.